# Is energy frame Invariant?

Tags: energy, energy-conservation, reference-frames

I know it isn't. But I have trouble understanding how energy conservation would work in that case.

I might be confused. Please explain.

Comment: The total energy is frame invariant. https://en.wikiversity.org/wiki/Invariant_energy

Comment: Energy is not frame invariant. But if you PICK a frame, energy is conserved. This is just like momentum.

Comment: @vs_292 That is restricted to a particular frame, just like conservation of momentum. If you switch frames halfway through the problem, none of your conservation laws hold.